# Compiling Vyper files results in a 'path exists outside base folder' error

Tags: web3js, truffle, vyper

[image]I was working with the **truffle VyperStorage Example Box**. When I execute `truffle compile` it shows me the error above. I have installed Vyper using pip.The truffle config.js file is used as default so no changes made to that either